# how to Upload the file during for loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have a list in which I upload a file for each record with Ajax, but because I am in a loop and I used ID for input, only the first record file is uploaded and the rest of the records are not uploaded.Please check the code

```
public class TaxParvande
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int projectId { get; set; }

    public String projectName { get; set; }

    public int listId { get; set; }

    public int year { get; set; }
    public bool state { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile? prosessMastand { get; set; }
    public int prosessId { get; set; }

    public String prosessName { get; set; }
    public String FilePath { get; set; }
  
    public String NaoaParvane { get; set; }
}
```

```
    <form asp-controller="Tax" asp-action="SabtEditTaxParvanedAsync" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


        <div class="container-fluid" style="overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden; direction:ltr ">

            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover  display" width="100%" style="direction:rtl;font-size:12px">
                <thead>

                    <tr class="table-head-blue text-center" style="background-color: #416992; color: white; position: sticky; top: 0;">

                        <th style="width:150px">وضعیت</th>
                        <th>پروسه پرونده</th>
                        <th>مستندات</th>
                        <th>تاریخ</th>

                    </tr>

                </thead>
                @{ var count = 0;}

                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)

                {
            <tr>
                <td style="width:150px">

                    <label class="switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" onchange="DisableRow(this)" asp-for="@Model.ToList()[i].state" value="True">
                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                    </label>
                </td>

                <td style="font-size: 12px">
                    <span>@Model.ToList()[i].prosessName</span>
                    <input class="d-none" value="@Model.ToList()[i].prosessName" name="[@i].prosessName" />

                </td>

                <td>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                        <div>

                            <span class="text-center mt-2" id="spnImageCartMlie" style="color: black;font-size: 12px"></span>

                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="button" required onclick="UploadImage()" value="Upload" class="btn btn-outline-danger " id="btnUpLoad" />

                            <div id="divmessage" class="text-center hidden m-2"></div>


                        </div>

                        <input id="mostanadPath" name="[@i].prosessMastand" type="file" class="">
                    </div>

                </td>
                <td style="font-size: 12px" hidden>
                    <span>@Model.ToList()[i].prosessId</span>
                    <input class="d-none" value="@Model.ToList()[i].prosessId" name="[@i].prosessId" />
                </td>

                <td>
                </td>


            </tr>
                    count++;
                }



            </table>
        </div>


        <div class=" text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-success  col-4 mb-2 " type="submit">ثبت اطلاعات</button>
        </div>

    </form>
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SabtEditTaxParvanedAsync([FromForm]IEnumerable<TaxParvande> taxParvandes)
    {
        if (taxParvandes == null)
        {
            return Content("File not selected");
        }
        foreach (var item in taxParvandes)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "ListUpload", item.prosessMastand.FileName);
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await item.prosessMastand.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Close();
            }

           
            var taxparvand = new TaxParvande
            {
                prosessId =item.prosessId,
                prosessName = item.prosessName,
                state = item.state,                    
                FilePath = path,
            };
            _context.Add(taxparvand);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
     

        return View();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your relevant `model`  to that it can be reproduced therefore,  can test.

Comment: In addition, could you please share what  this method returns `_uploadFiles.UploadFilesFunc(filearray, path);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Based on your comment, here is the complete view along with additional explanations:

```cs
@model IEnumerable< DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.TaxParvande>
<form asp-controller="YourContorllerName" asp-action="SabtEditTaxParvanedAsync" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden; direction:ltr ">

        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover  display" width="100%" style="direction:rtl;font-size:12px">
            <thead>

                <tr class="table-head-blue text-center" style="background-color: #416992; color: white; position: sticky; top: 0;">

                    <th style="width:150px">وضعيت</th>
                    <th>پروسه پرونده</th>
                    <th>مستندات</th>
                    <th>تاريخ</th>

                </tr>

            </thead>
            @{
                var count = 0;
            }

            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)

            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: 12px" hidden>
                        <span>@Model.ToList()[i].prosessId</span>
                        <input class="d-none" value="@Model.ToList()[i].prosessId" name="[@i].prosessId" />

                    </td>
                    <td style="width:150px">

                        <label class="switch">
                            <input type="checkbox" onchange="DisableRow(this)" asp-for="@Model.ToList()[i].state" value="True">
                            <span class="slider round"></span>
                        </label>
                    </td>

                    <td style="font-size: 12px">
                        <span>@Model.ToList()[i].prosessName</span>
                        <input class="d-none" value="@Model.ToList()[i].prosessName" name="[@i].prosessName" />

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                            <div>

                                <span class="text-center mt-2" id="spnImageCartMlie" style="color: black;font-size: 12px"></span>

                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="button" required onclick="UploadImage()" value="Upload" class="btn btn-outline-danger " id="btnUpLoad" />

                                <div id="divmessage" class="text-center hidden m-2"></div>


                            </div>

                            <input id="mostanadPath" name="[@i].prosessMastand" type="file" class="">
                        </div>

                    </td>


                    <td>
                    </td>


                </tr>
                count++;
            }

        </table>
    </div>

    <div class=" text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-success  col-4 mb-2 " type="submit"> Submit ثبت اطلاعات</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

**IWebHostEnvironment:**

Regarding the error on `_environment` you could replace to your `constructor name` this error is obvious as our constructor name was different. As I kept the name as below:

```
 private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;
```

You can set anything convenient for you.

**Controller Name:**

Even if you set `controller action` as `SabtEditTaxParvaned` it will works because it will check if there os any `POST` method within the controller. It will not works if there are many `POST` action. However,  you can replace it to `SabtEditTaxParvanedAsync`

**Previous Answer:**

> I have a list in which I upload a file for each record with Ajax, but
> because I am in a loop and I used ID for input, only the first record
> file is uploaded and the rest of the records are not uploaded

Based on your shared code it appeared that, you have two scenario

1. Single Upload When Click on Upload Button
2. All Upload Together When Click on Submit Button

As I have checked `Single Upload` which seems working as expected. However, for `List Upload` or `All Upload` you should required few modification in your code. Please follow the steps below:

**Model For List Upload:**

```cs
public class TaxParvande
    {
        public IFormFile? prosessMastand { get; set; }
        public int prosessId { get; set; }  
        public bool state { get; set; }  
        public string prosessName { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** As you said `"In a loop and I used ID for input"` Therefore, I have added `prosessId` which we will use in `View` later on.

**Controller:**

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SabtEditTaxParvanedAsync([FromForm]IEnumerable<TaxParvande> taxParvandes)
    {
        if (taxParvandes == null)
        {
            return Content("File not selected");
        }
        foreach (var item in taxParvandes)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "ListUpload", item.prosessMastand.FileName);
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await item.prosessMastand.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Close();
            }

           
            var taxDomainModel = new TaxDomainModel
            {
                prosessId =item.prosessId,
                prosessName = item.prosessName,
                state = item.state,                    
                FilePath = path,
            };
            _context.Add(taxDomainModel);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
     

        return View();
    }
```

**Note:** As you are submitting `FormData` thus we should redefine the controller as `[FromForm]` and the List of `IEnumerable<TaxParvande>`. As it is list therefore, we are looping through the items and `saving image` in folder finally getting the `path location` so that we can save in database.

**View:**

In `View` we will modify two things.

**Firstly,** for `Multiple FromData` we should use this attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to submit `bulk file` at once. Final change would as below

```
<form asp-controller="LoopUpload" asp-action="SabtEditTaxParvaned" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Secondly,** Use additional one `td` for `prosessId` and set the `attribute` as `hidden` just as below:

```
  <td style="font-size: 12px" hidden>
       <span>@Model.ToList()[i].prosessId</span>
       <input class="d-none" value="@Model.ToList()[i].prosessId" name="[@i].prosessId" />
  </td>
```

**Note:** You are all done to to upload a list together now. You can see the output below.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much brother. But there is a problem. Please give me the complete code of the view

Comment: i used         [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile? prosessMastand { get; set; }

Comment: I wrote the codes based on your code, but I encountered an error. I edited the codes in the question. Please test my codes.

Comment: (_environment) It showed me an error and I changed it to _webHostEnvironment and in form You wrote action asp-action="SabtEditTaxParvaned" while in controller SabtEditTaxParvanedAsync

Comment: Please test my codes and put the new codes together with the view. Thank you

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check if you able to fit this now.

Comment: Your answer worked correctly, but I have to upload a file for all the records in the table, if one of them is empty, the program will give an error. Please make a condition.It gives this error (NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Comment: No problem could you post new question for that, so that I can answer there, so make it seperate, as that has no relation with this issue. Stackoverflow incourage to make the problem unique. Hope you get it. We can work in another thread.

Comment: I asked the question, please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74314106/how-to-upload-a-single-file-in-the-list