# how to Upload a single file in the list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a list where I upload a file for each record and send them all together to the controller. The code works correctly, but if I don't upload a file for one of them and an empty record is sent, an error occurs.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SabtEditTaxParvanedAsync([FromForm]IEnumerable<TaxParvande> taxParvandes)
    {
        if (taxParvandes == null)
        {
            return Content("File not selected");
        }
        foreach (var item in taxParvandes)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "ListUpload", item.prosessMastand.FileName);
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await item.prosessMastand.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Close();
            }

           
            var taxDomainModel = new TaxDomainModel
            {
                prosessId =item.prosessId,
                prosessName = item.prosessName,
                state = item.state,                    
                FilePath = path,
            };
            _context.Add(taxDomainModel);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
     

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: What's error do you meet?

Comment: Based on condition you would like to upload file? I mean you don't want to upload the file already exist or whats your expectations?

Comment: Please try the solution, it will handle the `null reference exception error` upon the `empty file upload`

Comment: You would have one more case remain in future, that is, you might want to upload file on existing file, means want to replace the older file with the newer one. If you have this case feel free to share, will assist you on that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if I don't upload a file for one of them and an empty record is
> sent, an error occurs.

Well, in this scenario, you might encounter `null reference exception`. To overcome this error you could set `item.prosessMastand == null` then to `continue` loop which will skip the error upon `empty insertion`.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> SabtEditTaxParvanedAsync([FromForm] IEnumerable<TaxParvande> taxParvandes)
        {
            if (taxParvandes == null)
            {
                return Content("File not selected");
            }
            foreach (var item in taxParvandes)
            {
             

                if (item.prosessMastand == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }


                var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "ListUpload", item.prosessMastand.FileName);
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await item.prosessMastand.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    stream.Close();
                }


                var taxDomainModel = new TaxDomainModel
                {
                    prosessName = item.prosessName,
                    state = item.state,
                    filePath = path,
                };
                _context.Add(taxDomainModel);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

**Output:**
[image]